# Enviromnent variable for subprocess

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am trying to access an environment variable from a python process. I exported it like `export var=value`. This works fine for the command `pyton program.py` but not for `sudo python program.py`. How can I make sure the process can access the environment variable if it is started with sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default security policy for `sudo` normally prevents it from inheriting environment variables. However unless the particular variable is explicitly denied in your `sudoers` file, you should be able to allow it by specifying the `-E` option to sudo, e.g.

```
$ VAR="value" python -c 'import os; print os.environ.get("VAR")'
value
$ 
$ VAR="value" sudo python -c 'import os; print os.environ.get("VAR")'
None
$ 
$ VAR="value" sudo -E python -c 'import os; print os.environ.get("VAR")'
value
$
```

See `man sudo`

```
   -E          The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the
               security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
               existing environment variables.  The security policy may
               return an error if the -E option is specified and the user
               does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```